# MeteorJs: how to add multiple js and css file based on templates.?

Tags: jquery, css, meteor

I am in early phase of meteors and trying to learn how to integrate templates. I have free bootstrap templates which uses many js and css files. so how do i add / organize those js and css files in the project.

I have public folder with js , css, img folders. If i add my js and css files here how do i link in my templates and layout files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE**

I recently discovered that Meteor.startup is not a very reliable method. For me it worked on maybe 50% of the page refreshes. Please read my thread here:

[Meteor JS javascript files in main.* still don't load correctly. Best practices for load order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23632748/meteor-js-javascript-files-in-main-still-dont-load-correctly-best-practices/23633480?noredirect=1#23633480)

**Original Post**

I just did the same thing today.

[In Meteor JS, how to control Javascript load order in relation to DOM load order? For animations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23599997/in-meteor-js-how-to-control-javascript-load-order-in-relation-to-dom-load-order)

I created client/views/application/layout.html and pasted the template code into it.

I then removed the `<head>` code of the template (because Meteor adds that for you) and made the rest of the code into a `<template>`.

I put all the template's static assets like css, fonts, images, icons, and js in `public`

The scripts at the bottom of the template I commented out. Normally this stuff would load after the DOM is loaded, but in Meteor's case it does NOT due to Meteor's funky way of loading things:

(the below is what I commented out)

```
 <script src="assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <script src="assets/js/isotope.pkgd.min.js"></script>
 <script src="assets/js/imagesloaded.min.js"></script>
 <script src="assets/js/jquery.scrollTo.min.js"></script>
 <script src="assets/js/jquery.nav.min.js"></script>
 <script src="assets/js/jquery.appear.min.js"></script>
 <script src="assets/js/twitterFetcher.min.js"></script>
 <script src="assets/js/script.js"></script>
```

Since the above code does not load after the DOM loads due to Meteor, you have to specify the load order in another way.

I created layout.js in the same folder as layout.html and added this:

```
Meteor.startup( function () {
  $.getScript("assets/js/jquery.min.js");
  $.getScript("assets/js/bootstrap.min.js");
  $.getScript("assets/js/isotope.pkgd.min.js");
  $.getScript("assets/js/imagesloaded.min.js");
  $.getScript("assets/js/jquery.scrollTo.min.js");
  $.getScript("assets/js/jquery.nav.min.js");
  $.getScript("assets/js/jquery.appear.min.js");
  $.getScript("assets/js/twitterFetcher.min.js");
  $.getScript("assets/js/script.js");
});
```

And now the template works. When `Meteor.startup` is called inside the `client` folder, it will load the contents after the DOM is loaded, which is exactly what we wanted to do with those javascript files.

Comment: I will give a try this and let you know, thanks for your help.

Comment: Hey, I recently discovered that Meteor.startup is not a very reliable method. Please check out my post here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23632748/meteor-js-javascript-files-in-main-still-dont-load-correctly-best-practices/23633480?noredirect=1#23633480

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at https://github.com/oortcloud/unofficial-meteor-faq and the Where should I put my files? section in that. Should give you everything you need to know.

Comment: Great thanks for info, its a great faq to go through.